# How to receive mail in Qmail?

Tags: email

I've a server that uses Qmail. It is installed by default and it is supposed to work. I've created a new domain and new user (vadddomain + vadduser) without problems, but when I send an email from Gmail to webmaster@domain.com (the address I've created) it desappears, it is. But if connect to SMTP server directly (*telnet domain.com 25*) and post an email it arrives to the user queue. What's happening?!?

Note: If I try to access to my user through *telnet domain.com 110* it seems my pwd is not correct and it's the same I used when created the user with *vadduser*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you require for mail to arrive at your machine:

- Your server must be configured to accept mail for the domain - which you've done.
- DNS records must point to your machine, such that remote hosts know where mail is sent.

I'd imagine if you are missing an MX record then gmail will eventually show you a bounce message, but as a sanity check please check you have an MX record for your domain pointing at your servers IP address.

Something like this should show you if you have a record:

```
dig -t mx domain.com
```

Comment: It seems I don't have the MX records. I've changed, and still doesn't works, but I suppose it will take some hours to propagate..